# Is there a way to hide the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, hide

Is there a way to hide the Javascript in the page?
I don't want to let the user check the ajax methods in my webpage, it's just a matter of internal security. Thank you!

My only worry is that, in AJAX i will pass the post/get parameters and the page address. Maybe I should just try a way to secure that page..

Comment: No there is none. You can obfuscate it and make it look difficult to human eye but the client browser still has to be able to see and parse it so no you can't

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to Google.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with "make it look difficult to human eye"? Can you give me some tip?

Comment: Security through obscurity is the weakest form of security. You're better off spending your time making sure your code is secure, rather than hidden.

Comment: Hiding or obscuring your JavaScript is not an effective security measure. You will need to secure your AJAX calls in another way. In other words, what @AlexanderOMara said while I was typing this.

Comment: Don't pass secure things around via javascript output.  Store them on the server with a temporary, unique key sent to the javascript.  Use other security measures like `@Html.AntiforgeryToken()` in ASP.NET MVC, for example, to prevent cookie hijacking for POSTs, and always sanitize user input and have server-side validation in place before javascript validation.  There are numerous books written for security, but hiding javascript is a mid- to late- '90s idea.  There  areseveral sites that could reverse any kind of javascript obfuscation, even back then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't a way to "hide" Javascript. Javascript is interpreted locally by the client web browser.

What you can do is to "compress" (minify) the Javascript, so it's really difficult to read.

Try this (paste your JS source and it will minify it): http://jscompress.com
Also: http://javascript-minifier.com

Answer (score 2):

No. Everything can be viewed from DevTools. Hiding your JS isn't a solid nor valid form of security.

Answer (score -1):

No way to hide Javacript. It belongs to web client side. Every client can see it just by view source code.
You can do compress it by this tool: http://jscompress.com/

Comment: You managed to give the same answer as Alejandro Iván, only 18 minutes later.